# I can't prefill the HTML form with embed url

Tags: php, html, forms

I am developing a mobile app and creating an admin panel for this app. I want to create a video object with html form in web, and fetch it from mobile app. I can create this video object with html form.  I want to update this object with html form by prefilling the video create form, all the fields are prefilled right except embed url input text. Because of embed url containing ' " ' (double quotes) an error is occuring. Here is my html update form:

```
   <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="egzersizVideoUrl">Video Embed Url</label>
                                    <input type="url" class="form-control"
                                           name="egzersizVideoUrl" id="egzersizVideoUrl"
                                           value="<?php echo $exercise['video_embed_url']; ?>">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="egzersizPopularite">Popülarite Skoru</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                           name="egzersizPopularite" id="egzersizPopularite"
                                           value="<?php echo $exercise['popularity']; ?> ">
                                </div>
```

and this is the result

[Update form resut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUci6.png)

I want to prefill the input field with youtube embed url, how can I do this in right way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: My apologies, what you're looking for is htmlentities

```
<input type="url" class="form-control" name="egzersizVideoUrl" id="egzersizVideoUrl" value="<?php echo htmlentities($exercise['video_embed_url']); ?>">
```

This will convert any double quotes to the corresponding html entity.

Comment: Thank you for reply but with this version it only add a slash and the result now <iframe width=\ instead of <iframe width=

Comment: @ErtuğrulUzun Apologies, answer updated - can you try that?

Comment: Now it works, thank you so much. I can't upvote the answer because of my reputation.

Comment: @ErtuğrulUzun No problem! If you need to decode the string again check out html_entity_decode()